# Uncaught [Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Basically I am importing `componentB` into `componentA`

and in `componentA` im basically doing something like

```
const ComponentA = () => {
   const ComponentB = blah.map(() => {

   })
  //more stuff
  return(
    <div> stuff here </div>
  )
}
```

but when I run the tests (already built) for `ComponentA` file they blow up with that error message

both components are correctly connected to the store:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentA)`

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentB)`

what would cause that error?

I know before I've had to import it differently. currently im just importing it like this: `import componentB from '/components'`

but I did try `import { componentB } from '/components'` so just exporting the component by passing the store but then it doesn't work coz it comes unconnected from the store

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you're testing redux connected components you need to render them with a fake store, or in-memory store. Usually best practice is to render the un-connected component as `import {component} from '...';` and then pass down the props that your component is expecting. The redux library already has test cases so there's no point duplicating that work.

Comment: my problem is that if I import `componentB` using `{ componentB }` then it'll break the code. im not directly importing it into the test file but rather into `componentA` and then `componentA` tests are failing. does that make sense?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find a solution?